# sequence converges in $\mathbb R \Rightarrow$ all subsequences converge (thinking about different proofs)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

I'm sure there are a lot of ways to show this. I also saw one or two in the past but thanks to my good memory I'm here again.
The problem is :

Let $u_n$ be a sequence that converges to $u \in \mathbb R$. Show that a subsequence 
of $u_n$ also converges to the same limit.That is : for all sequences $m_k;$ $\ \ m,k \in \mathbb N \ $ with $  \ m_{k+1}>m_{k}$, $\ \ \forall k \in \mathbb N$we have : $v_k:=u_{m_k} \rightarrow u, \ \  k \rightarrow \infty$

Ideas:

($1$)

One way would be to use $m_k \geq k$ wich is straightforword by induction.Since we know that : $\forall \ \epsilon > 0 \ \exists n_0 \in \mathbb N : \forall n\geq n_0  |u_n-u|< \epsilon$ , we can always pick a $k \geq n_0$ and have the convergence condition on $m_k$ :  $m_k \geq n_0,\forall k  \geq n_0$ hence $|u_{m_k}-u|< \epsilon$.

($2$)

Another way: using the same convegence condition as above and the same $n_0$.
I use the fact that $n_0$ is finite and $m_k$ monoton. increasing in $\mathbb N$  to state that : $ \exists k_0 \in \mathbb N : m_{k_0}\geq n_0$. Then we have that : $\forall k\geq k_0 , m_k \geq n_0$ (since $m_k$ is monot. increasing) and the convergence follows as in ($1$).

I would like know if the ideas are correct.I'm still not totaly sure if the reasoning is right,espacially in ($2$).Thanks in advance!

Comment: Let $(s_n)$ be a any sequence in $\mathbb R$. Let S be the set of subsequential limits of $(s_n)$. Then the limit of $(s_n)$ exists iff S contains one element. This implies that a sequence converges only if all of it subsequences converge to the same limit. All subsequence must not only converge, but they must converge to the same limit. Or are you asking whether a sequence (whose all of it subsequences converge) can diverge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the 2) is correct because if you couldn't find a $k_0$ : $m_{k_0}\geq n_0$ then the sequence {$m_{k}$} would be finite,which is not